# API methods family naming rules

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naming-conventions

Would you call a family of API methods *(more easy to find for programmers)*

- Rectangle
- RectangleRounded
- RectangleInflated

or *(more easy to read in fluent English)*

- Rectangle
- RoundedRectangle
- InflatedRectangle

?

Where can I find a pros vs. cons discussion about this topic?

Thanks.

Comment: [dont ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here" and if you're looking for a [discussion elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or *other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: Unrelated note about the [tag:visual-studio]. If you read the description, it says *DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.*, so it should not be used in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recommends (and uses in .NET framework) the form: RoundedRectangle.

MS provides very usefull [Naming Guidlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) document. You can find the following in  **Names of Classes, Structs, and Interfaces** chapter:

> CONSIDER ending the name of derived classes with the name of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find something, that specifically talks about your exact topic, but I found this, which merely addresses your question:

> - ThingAbstract: "Abstract" suffix. Unnatural language. Appears next to ThingInterface in file listings.
> - AbstractThing: "Abstract" prefix. Natural language. Far off from ThingInterface in file listings.
>
> <sub>Source:
> https://www.drupal.org/project/coding_standards/issues/1567920</sub>

Beside the mentioning of the naturalness, it talks about the listing order, which could help understanding the structure of a project (alltough subfolders should compensate for that).

Here is another answer on stackoverflow, which states

> As for the names of classes, it would be typical to prefix the class name with the specialization [..]
>
> <sub>Source: [The C# namespace and class/sub-class naming conventions when the top namespace contains the base class and inner namespaces contain sub-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301283/the-c-sharp-namespace-and-class-sub-class-naming-conventions-when-the-top-namesp/1301307#1301307)</sub>

---

I think, it's mostly opinion based and personally I would prefer the second way (RoundedRectangle) as it is more natural to read and therefore to understand. Also I think (and as I read often online), we should try to make the class names as significant as possible.